# Spring Cloud Config no detecta los property source

Tags: spring

Buenas tengo un problema no entiendo bien porque sucede espero puedan ayudarme, primero doy contexto

Estoy haciendo una api con un arquitectura de microservicios todos con Spring Boot y cree un servicio que se hace de servidor de configuración con spring cloud server y al realizar todo me di cuenta que el servidor no detecta los archivos de configuración paso a mostrarles como estan:

El application.yml del config service es:

```yml
---
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/MarcossIC/Microservice-example.git
          search-path: config-data
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: config-service
...
```

La clase main del config service es:

```java
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Luego como ejemplo muestro el archivo de uno de los microservicios que probé y no funciona:

el bootstrap.yml del user-service (Es uno de los micro servicios)

```yml
---
spring:
  banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: user-service
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8081
...
```

y el archivo de configuración yml que debería de utilizar el config service para el micro servicio user service es

```yml
---
server:
  port: 8001
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
...
```

En las dependencias en el user service agregue estas dependencias para spring cloud

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

y en el archivo de Pom del config server agregue el server de spring cloud.

En si estos son los archivos que creo estan involucrados, mi tema es que el servidor se levanta correctamente, se conecta correctamente a Git, pero al probar no detecta los archivos de configuración al probar con Postman e intentar traer la configuración me dice esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa en la imagen, hago un llamado a un endpoint que spring cloud proporciona por defecto y el path del endopint se compone del nombre del servicio que deseas configurar en este caso "user-service" y la propiedad "default" hace referencia a que el "profile" es el por defecto. Bueno en la propiedad "propertySource" deberían de aparecer las configuraciones del archivo "user-service.yml"  pero como se ve estan vacias

Ademas, al ejecutar el proyecto user-service en consola se ve que el servicio se ejecuta con el servidor pero no aplica las configuraciones lo se porque para empezar se ejecuta con el puerto por defecto y no con el que estoy definiendo en el archivo

Agrego la estructura de carpetas no se si da problemas el path

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es algo normal hay veces que lo no coge. no hay una epxlicacion. yo lo he intentado mil veces hasta con el repo en local y nolo coge un micro si y otro no a pesar de tner la misma config

Comment: Al final no encontré solución, entonces opte por dejar de usar spring cloud para la configuración centralizada y tener todas las config separadas